# Accessing directories and files Mathematica Online

Tags: mathematica-online

How does one access folders of Mathematica Online for `Import`-ing and `Export`-ing?

For instance, suppose I have created a folder called Data. On the desktop version, I could use something like `SetDirectory["C:\Documents\Data"]` and could then `Import` and `Export` directly to that folder. I have no idea how to do this with the online version.

The command `Directory` returns something inscrutable like `/wolframcloud/userfiles/e8f/e8f19ada-103e-43444db295fc`.

Is there documentation anywhere for this? (Sorry, that's a second question.)

Comment: If you execute `FileNames[]`, do you see the `Data` folder you created? How did you create that folder in the first place?

Comment: No, `FileNames[]` only gives names of files, not directories. The directory was made through the browser-based GUI.

Comment: Despite its name, `FileNames` also returns names of directories. You can check that on your local installation.

Comment: Sure enough, you are right. I checked before commenting before, and somehow missed it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the question, the command `Directory[]` will return something like `/wolframcloud/userfiles/e8f/e8f19ada-103e-43444db295fc`. That is the Home directory/folder. If a sub-directory/folder of Home is Data, then one can use `SetDirectory[/wolframcloud/userfiles/e8f/e8f19ada-103e-43444db295fc/Data/]` to set the current directory to Data.